# How to get Kerberos TGS and use it in a GUI application in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, frame, kerberos

i'm trying to make an application with the Keberos protocol and the GSS-API in Java, and i've already made the authentication and the context establishement before calling the doAsPrivileged method.
In this method I get the mutual authentication sending a simple token from the client to the server, but after that i want to make some other things.

I want to open a new window with a table of products to let the client select them and buy something and that was connected to a database in the server.

my question is about how can a i use this context in other frames that are diferent from the original doAsPrivileged action class.

i get an error GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt) and i don't know how can i find this TGT to send it more than one time to the server.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6682166/696632) as well.
Your code fails because Java tries to use GSSAPI with the default login config name. Which is `com.sun.security.jgss.initiate`. To perform a GSS call for someone else or with another login conf name you have to use the `LoginContext`, obtain the subject and then do a `doAs`. As far as I can see, every action involving ticket exchange has to be done in a `PrivilegedAction` if you don't stick to the defaults. That's why our stuff's failing :-(